# Remote rest web service call using phalconphp

Tags: rest, phalcon, remote-server

I want to call API using Phalcon Php framework.
example:
http://example.com?key=abc

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Phalcon has no internally build way to ask other services.

You can use either client built in incubator project:

https://github.com/phalcon/incubator/tree/master/Library/Phalcon/Http/Client

or a standard connection class as Guzzle, or native php curl methods.

Comment: Friend how i can install Guzzle because i am new in Phalcon and i am using docker.

Comment: Please, read the docks, "getting started"-s especially. Start with composer.